# Query related to Cordova.exec when called multiple times

Tags: java, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using cordova to make calls to the plugin file.

```
cordova.exec(onFileSystemSuccess, onFileSystemFailure, "ABCPlugin", "echo",[arg1, arg2]);
```

If the exec function is called 2 or more time I need a way to initialize the object only once.

e.g StandardFileSystemManager manager = new StandardFileSystemManager(); // which will be in the plugin file

But use only the once created value of the manager object.

i.e Say exec call calls the plugin file once, the object manager gets created.
The second time exec is called I want to reuse the value of manager object already initialize.

Hope this is clear or else let me know. I just want to know if this is possible so that, the I will not have to created the manager object multiple times

Answer (score 2):

You can store your manager variable as a member variable in your Java class of plugin, make it null at start (constructor), and check if it is still null when you receive init call and create it accordingly. Cordova plugin classes are (singletons) created once in app lifetime, you are always using the same instance.

Comment: can you explain a bit more may be

Comment: I need a question to answer :) Basically, your question is not really related to Cordova, it is general programming issue about Java (I think)